# i need to create and remove html elements

Tags: javascript

I need to create and remove html elements but remove function doesn't work.

```
<script>
function addElement() {

  var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');

  var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');

  var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;

      numi.value = num;

  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

  var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';

  newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);

  newdiv.innerHTML = 'Element Number '+num+' has been added! <a href="#\" onclick="removeElement('+divIdName+')">Remove the div  '+divIdName+' </a>';

  ni.appendChild(newdiv);

}
function removeElement(divNum) {

  var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');

  var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);

  d.removeChild(olddiv);

}
</script>


<input type="hidden" value="0" id="theValue" />

<p><a href="javascript:;" onclick="addElement();">Add Some Elements</a></p>

<div id="myDiv"> </div>
```

I tried really.

Comment: When the site asks you to add more text to your description it doesn't mean to paste the title multiple times.

Comment: @j08691 just to make it clear, he needs to create and remove html elements but remove function dosnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the argument in quotes since it is a string.

```
newdiv.innerHTML = 'Element Number '+num+' has been added! <a href=\"#\" onclick="removeElement(\''+divIdName+'\')">Remove the div  '+divIdName+' </a>';
```

Below is the working snippet

```js
function addElement() {

  var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');

  var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');

  var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;

      numi.value = num;

  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

  var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';

  newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);

  newdiv.innerHTML = 'Element Number '+num+' has been added! <a href=\"#\" onclick="removeElement(\''+divIdName+'\')">Remove the div  '+divIdName+' </a>';

  ni.appendChild(newdiv);

}
function removeElement(divNum) {

  var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');

  var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);

  d.removeChild(olddiv);

}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="theValue" />

<p><a href="javascript:;" onclick="addElement();">Add Some Elements</a></p>

<div id="myDiv"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks  . i was tried really :(